# Movie about an astronaut getting controlled by an alien

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember watching a movie about an astronaut returning from space and becoming sick. Later, he dies from his sickness and his wife realizes an alien was controlling him. soon she starts to get sick and controlled by the alien. I think she gives birth to the alien, but I'm unsure.

Comment: I remember watching it a while ago, like in the 2010s and the movie was in English. I don't remember anything else sadly.

Comment: I also remember the movie's setting being dark in color.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like [The Astronaut's Wife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Astronaut%27s_Wife) starring Johnny Depp and Charlize Theron (1999)

- Astronaut returns from space and acts strangely
- Alien controlling body of astronaut and then his wife
- Gets wife pregnant